# How to re-visit to the same view function if false in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a request form from the user

- I am trying to create a directory
- If exists i need to revert back saying change fname,phonenu

  ```
  @app.route('/sub')
  def sub():
      if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.form.get('fname ')
        phonenu = request.form.get('phonenu')
        dirName = os.path.join('static', fname + phonenu )
        if not os.path.exists(dirName):
              os.mkdir(dirName)
              print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
        return render_template('form.html')
  ```

Form.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="/sub"  enctype = "multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <label> First Name</label>  <input type="text" name="fname " >
    <br><br/>
     <label> Phone No </label> <input  id="phonenu" name="phonenu" maxlength="10" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" > <br><br>
    <input type="submit" class='btn success' value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `redirect()` to redirect the user, it receives a required parameter for destination URL to redirect. Normally you will use `url_for()` to build the URL, pass the current view function's name, so it will redirect the user to the same URL/view:

```
from flask import redirect, url_for

@app.route('/sub', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sub():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...
        if not os.path.exists(dirName):
            os.mkdir(dirName)
            print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
            return redirect(url_for('sub'))  # <-- this line
    return render_template('form.html')
```

Besides, you will need to set methods (`methods=['GET', 'POST']`) for `app.route()` to allow POST method.